# SpringBoot Gradle plugin does not repackage a Maven submodule (workaround inside)

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

My SpringBoot project depends on a big Maven project :

*aSpringBootProject/build.gradle :*

```
...
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'my.big:maven.dependency'
    ...
}
```

This big Maven project depends on a subModule that just include dependencies :

*bigMavenDependency/pom.xml*

```
...
<dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
        <group>my.big</group>
        <artefact>sub.module</artefact>
    </dependency>
    ...
</dependencies>
```

*bigSubModule/pom.xml*

```
...
<package>pom</package>
...
<dependencies>
    <!-- a lot of dependencies here -->
</dependencies>
```

When I build my bootJar and run it (`java -jar aSpringBootProject.jar`) I have this error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to get nested archive for entry BOOT-INF/lib/sub-module-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.archive.JarFileArchive.getNestedArchive(JarFileArchive.java:108)
...
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to open nested jar file 'BOOT-INF/lib/sub-module-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom'
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile.getNestedJarFile(JarFile.java:254)
...   
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to find ZIP central directory records after reading 2628 bytes
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.CentralDirectoryEndRecord.<init>(CentralDirectoryEndRecord.java:65)
```

Unpacking my bootJar give me a pom file where a lot of jar files were expected.

The `gradle bootRun` command works like a charm.

A workaround is to exclude the submodule and then add it as a dependency in my build.gradle :

```
...
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'my.big:maven.dependency' {
        exclude 'my.big:sub.module'
    }
    implementation 'my.big:sub.module'
    ...
}
```

Where am I wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
...
<dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
        <group>my.big</group>
        <artefact>sub.module</artefact>
        (here try <packaging>jar</packaging> or <type>jar</type>)
    </dependency>
    ...
</dependencies>
```

I had the same issue in gradle, when using `compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson', name: 'jackson-bom', version: '2.9.8', ext: 'pom'` with spring's boot-jar. When i removed `, ext: 'pom'` the problem got resolved.

Comment: I will try. Thx